# Is there a way to force prisma not to use sql parameters?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

Using the Prisma ORM, most data is changed into a sql parameter. This is usually reasonable behavior, because unvalidated user input should be parameterized to prevent injection attacks.

However, Prisma seems to still use parameterization on back end info. For example, for a typed field logType and a constant array `logtypesWeCareAbout` here:

```
    const jobLogs = await prisma.log.findMany({
        where: {
            logType: {
                in: logtypesWeCareAbout,
            },
        },
        orderBy: {
            createdAt: 'desc',
        },
    });
```

Looking at the query plan, if `logTypesWeCareAbout` is 20 items long, prisma will create 20 parameters, to the point that it becomes a serious impact on the query's performance. Although I can't say whether this is because of prisma or postgres, a largeish `in` statement can take seconds to resolve in some cases, even if the unparameterized version runs in reasonable time.

Is there a way to force prisma to use the contents of the array raw instead of parameterizing each item in the array?

Answer (score 0):

While Prisma does offer a significant degree of convenience and security with its SQL parameterization, as you've observed, there can be instances where this approach might adversely impact query performance, particularly with large IN statements.

Currently, Prisma doesn't provide a direct mechanism to bypass SQL parameterization for specific queries within its high-level query API. However, it does offer raw database access methods, which can give you more granular control over your SQL queries when necessary, albeit with some trade-offs.

Prisma Client exposes four methods that allow you to send raw queries:

$queryRaw: Returns actual records (e.g., for SELECT statements).
$executeRaw: Returns a count of affected rows (e.g., after an UPDATE or DELETE operation).
$queryRawUnsafe: Returns actual records using a raw string, but with a potential SQL injection risk​1​.
Here's an example of using $queryRaw:

```
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = ${email}`;
```

Prisma uses tagged templates for these methods, which can mitigate SQL injection risks by creating safe prepared statements​1​.

However, there are important considerations when using these raw query methods:

Template variables cannot be used inside SQL string literals.
Variables can only be used for data values, not for identifiers such as column names, table names, or database names, or for SQL keywords.
$queryRaw and $queryRawUnsafe map any database values returned to their corresponding JavaScript types.
$queryRaw does not support dynamic table names in PostgreSQL databases​1​.
These methods return an array where each object corresponds to a database record​1​.

Remember that typing with $queryRaw might present mismatches between the raw data and the TypeScript type inferred. For instance, a Boolean field in the Prisma model might not necessarily correspond to the type in the raw SQL results​1​.

With these methods, you could write a custom query without SQL parameters for your specific use case. However, you should be aware that this approach can increase the risk of SQL injection, and potentially bypass some of the safety measures provided by the ORM. Thus, it's recommended to use raw queries judiciously and only when necessary. Always validate user input where applicable, and only use trusted data in your queries to minimize this risk.

In summary, while Prisma doesn't offer a way to force the bypassing of SQL parameters within its high-level query API, the raw query methods $queryRaw and $queryRawUnsafe give you an alternative route to handle special cases where you require more control over your SQL queries.

Comment: Many of your answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). 

If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.